# How can I open a .db file generated by eclipse(android) form DDMS-->File explorer-->data--->data-->packagename-->database?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, cordova

The .db file is generated from eclipse(android) form  DDMS-->File explorer-->data--->data-->package name-->database. Then I select the database and click "push a file from device", and save it as .db file. How can I view this database?

Comment: it will possible in emulator, not in real device unless its a rooted device.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I Understood correctly you need to view the .db file that you extracted from internal storage of Emulator. If that's the case use this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

to view the db.

You can also use a firefox extension

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

EDIT: For online tool use :
https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: How to open the .db file inside the sqlite-manager firefox addon? I can't open .db file its asking for .sqlite files only.

Comment: This program is good but is there any good portable alternative which don't require 100MB of disc space?

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to browse your database is to use questoid sqlite manager.

# 1. Download questoid manager from this [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/usHZdRdz/comquestoidsqlitemanager_100.html) .

# 2. Drop this file into your eclipse --> dropins.

# 3. Restart your eclipse.

# 4. Now go to your file explorer and click your database. you can find a blue database icon enabled in the top right corner.

# 5. Double click the icon and you can see ur inserted fields/tables/ in the database

Answer (score 2):

Download this Sqlite manager its the easiest one to use
[Sqlite manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/)

and drag and drop your fetched file on its running instance

only drawback of this **Sqlite Manager** it stop responding if you run some SQL statement that has Syntax Error in it.

So i Use Firefox Plugin Side by side also which you can find at [FireFox addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform you can use: **sqlite3 file_name.db** from the terminal. **.tables** will list the tables, **.schema** is full layout. SQLite commands like: **select * from table_name;** and such will print out the full contents. Type: ".exit" to exit. No need to download a GUI application.Use a semi-colon if you want it to execute a single command. Decent SQLite usage tutorial http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/sqlite-command-examples/